# Exception error trying to ping with a timer

Tags: vb.net, timer

I've beeen getting this error I cannot seem to solve with try...catch and I want your advice on how to solve this. There's more code but I believe it has to do with the error i'm getting.
The code is this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim ip As String
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    ip = "some.ip.com"
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(ip) Then
            ping = (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
            Label1.Text = ping & "ms"
            sw.Stop()
            MsgBox("You have no connection.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
    If ping < 200 Then
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Green
        Label2.Text = "Good Connection"
    ElseIf ping > 200 Then
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Label2.Text = "Medium connection"
    ElseIf ping > 400 Then
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Label2.Text = "Bad Connection"
    ElseIf ping <= 0 Then
        Label2.Text = "No Connection"
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Brown
    End If
```

The error gives me exception error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
  at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
  at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout,     Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.Ping(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.Ping(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Sky_Casino.Form2.Timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\tonakis2108\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\something\something\Form2.vb:line 61
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

What I want my code to do is ping the target, return ping in ms via the sw and do this every 5 seconds.

I get this error when I plug my connection off to test for errors while I am connected to the program. Can anyone help?

Comment: It doesn't know what machine is "some.ip.com".  I don't either.  When you unplug the cable then you'll of course also lose the connection to the DNS server and the ability to resolve "some.ip.com" to an IP address.

Comment: Why can't you "seem to solve with try...catch"?  You probably don't want to show the message box when an exception occurs, but presumably the exception is being caught?  Can you just set `ping = -1` in the catch block?

Comment: @Mark what do you mean?
I want to show the ping to the users in ms I meant to say that try...catch isn't working cause I still get the exception on the timer it seems.

Comment: @Tonakis2108 the exception will still occur, and you will still display the error message, but that's the point of Try/Catch - you can decide how to handle it.  I'll add an answer with "working" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the Try/Catch is that the exception will still occur, but you can handle it as you want, instead of the program crashing.  The following code will handle the errors more gracefully, and I also rearranged your checks for the ping time, since your combination of less than and greater than checks isn't going to give you what you want, and added a longer timeout (the default is 500ms).  Still not the greatest code, but for me it handles the network being disconnected!

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim ip = "www.google.com"
    Dim timeout = 1000
    Dim sw = New Stopwatch()
    Try
        Dim ping As Long = -1
        sw.Start()
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(ip, timeout) Then
            sw.Stop()
            ping = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
            Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}ms", ping)
        End If
        If ping < 0 Then
            Label2.Text = "Ping Timed Out"
            Label2.BackColor = Color.Brown
        ElseIf ping < 200 Then
            Label2.Text = "Good Connection"
            Label2.BackColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf ping < 400 Then
            Label2.Text = "Medium Connection"
            Label2.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Else
            Label2.Text = "Bad Connection"
            Label2.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = ex.Message
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if it works this way I came upon the answer to my problems by observing the location to which my studio was building my application. The code though works great and I really want to thank you about helping with my request even if it was something I may have caused by mistake. Thanks again and sorry for the trouble. (Too bad i cannot +1 the answer). :(